# Giving input to a shell script through command line

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file like this with .sh extension..

```
clear
echo -n "Enter file name: "
read FILE
gcc -Wall -W "$FILE" && ./a.out
echo
```

When I can execute this file, it asks for a .c file and when given, it compiles and gives output of the .c file.

For this, everytime I have to first execute this .sh file and then give it the .c file name when asked. Is there anyway, so that, I can just give the .c file in the command line itself, so that it takes that file and does the work...

What I mean is, if I give "./file.sh somecommand cfile.c", then it takes cfile.c as input, compiles it and gives the output...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use '$1' variable:

```
clear
gcc -Wall -W $1 && ./a.out
echo
```

$1 means "first argument from the command line".

Alternatively, if you want to compile multiple files at once using your script, you can use $@ variable, on example:

```
gcc -Wall -W $@ && ./a.out
```

You will invoke your script as follows (assuming it's called 'script.sh'):

```
./script.sh file.c
```

Plase see section 3.2.5 of the [following article](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html).

If your project gets bigger, you may also want to consider using tools designated for building, like [automake](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/).

Answer (score 1):

You can also have it do things either way:

```
if [ -n "$1" ] ; then
    FILE="$1"
else
    echo -n "Enter file name: "
    read FILE
fi
gcc -Wall -W "$FILE" && ./a.out
```

This will use the command line argument if it is there, otherwise it asks for a file name.